# How to choose preferred date of add-in publication

Tags: office365, office-js, office-store, excel-online

guys!
Currently, I'm working on an investigation of an add-in publishing process. I've not submitted any solutions to the AppSource yet, that is why my question may be silly.

So, the question is the next, is it possible to choose a preferred date for add-in publication in AppSource? For example, we send an add-in to Certification approval and it is resolved on Aug 31. But we want that our add-in becomes publicly available in AppSource only in the mid of September. Is there is a way how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can specify availability when you create your listing in Partner Center.

See [Specify availability for your Office solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/specify-availability#schedule)